# JxBrowser doesn't start

Tags: java, jxbrowser

Used JxBrowser throughout evaluation and worked perfectly. Now suddenly it isn't working as soon as I launch. I'm running on Mac OS X 10.11, however I've tested this on Windows as well and still doesn't work. I have the required libraries for both operating systems in my build paths. and this is what I get (running on Mac OS X):

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPCException: Failed to initialize IPC. Remote process doesn't respond.
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPC.a(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPC.start(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.evh98.vision.apps.NetflixScreen.start(NetflixScreen.java:33)
at com.evh98.vision.Vision.setScreen(Vision.java:148)
at com.evh98.vision.screens.MediaScreen$1.handle(MediaScreen.java:95)
at com.evh98.vision.screens.MediaScreen$1.handle(MediaScreen.java:1)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:3965)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3911)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2040)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2502)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:197)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:147)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$349(GlassViewEventHandler.java:228)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$165/454694532.get(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:227)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:546)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:956)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that you initialize browser core functionality in non-UI thread in your JavaFX application as described in JxBrowser [documentation](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013071-using-jxbrowser-in-javafx).