# JxBrowser didn't work on Mac

Tags: macos, eclipse-plugin, jxbrowser, swt-awt

I am trying to use `JxBrowser` in Eclipse plugin by following https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013072-using-jxbrowser-in-swt.

Here's part of my code:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.awt.SWT_AWT;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.BrowserView;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser;

@Override 
public void init() {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (Environment.isMac()) {
                BrowserCore.shutdown();
            }
        }

    });
}

@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Browser browser = new Browser();
    BrowserView view = new BrowserView(browser);
    Composite composite = new Composite(parent, 
            SWT.EMBEDDED | SWT.NO_BACKGROUND);
    Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(composite);
    frame.add(view);

    browser.loadURL("http://html5test.com");
}
```

It works well on Windows and Ubuntu.

But I got exception on Mac:

```
com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPCException: Failed to initialize IPC. Remote process doesn't respond.
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPC.a(SourceFile:158)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPC.start(SourceFile:127)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.<init>(SourceFile:224)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.<init>(SourceFile:184)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.<init>(SourceFile:151)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.<init>(SourceFile:137)
at myaction.editors.MyFxEditor.createPartControl(MyFxEditor.java:139)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:151)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:99)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:341)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:898)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:879)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:121)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:345)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:264)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:104)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:73)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:55)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:971)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:640)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:746)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:711)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:695)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:99)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:186)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:145)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4781)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:211)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:85)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:59)
at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:572)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:536)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:724)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:396)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1166)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3252)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$25(WorkbenchPage.java:3167)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3149)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3144)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3108)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3089)
at myaction.handlers.SampleHandler.execute(SampleHandler.java:41)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:295)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:252)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:234)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:493)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:486)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:799)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(HandledContributionItem.java:675)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.access$7(HandledContributionItem.java:659)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem$4.handleEvent(HandledContributionItem.java:592)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4230)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1491)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1514)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1499)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1299)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4072)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3698)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
```

Environment:

```
 OS: MacOS Sierra 10.12.2
 JDK: 1.8.0_73
 Eclipse: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) Build id: 20160218-0600
```

I did some searching and got a simlar question here: [JxBrowser doesn't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37795754/jxbrowser-doesnt-start), but it didn't work for me. Seems nothing about `BrowserCore.initialize()` since it's in `SWT` model.

Comment: Could you add a sysout right before the `BrowserCore.shutdown()` to see if it's being fired early for some reason?

Comment: The issue you see in your SWT application is probably related to a deadlock issue that is reproducible when heavyweight (default) rendering mode is enabled. You can try solving it by using the "jxbrowser.ipc.external=true" VM parameter that enables lightweight rendering mode and runs Chromium engine in separate native process to avoid deadlocks between SWT-Swing/JavaFX-Chromium. Please try this VM parameter.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, may be we have to initialize it on a separate thread (non-ui) the browser object.